# Can not find entry in ldap with ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have the following ldap entries for a group and a user and I want to test the memberof overlay.

```
dn: cn=authentication,dc=groups, dc=groupTestMemberOf, dc=application, dc=company, dc=de
description: Authentication Gruppe
objectClass: customGroup
member: uid=userTestMemberOf,dc=users,dc=company,dc=de
cn: authentication

dn: uid=userTestMemberOf,dc=users,dc=company,dc=de
cn: test userTestMemberOf
givenName: test
sn: userTestMemberOf
uid: userTestMemberOf
mail: userTestMemberOf@company.com
objectClass: top
objectClass: customUser
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
employeeType: person
```

Now I want to test it with the ldapsearch command, but I always get the result `32 No such object`.

My command is

`ldapsearch -v -x -b uid=userTestMemberOf,dc=users,dc=company,dc=de dn memberof`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the username and password in the ldapsearch...

The correct command has to be

`ldapsearch -v -x -D *DNofUSER* -w *PW* -b "dc=users,dc=company,dc=de" "(uid=userTestMemberOf)" dn memberof`

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `memberOf` is missing in your user entry, so it can't be retrieved.

It could be because :

- You do not have (correctly) loaded/activated/configured the memberOf overlay
- The member in the group was added before the memberOf overlay was activated
- There is an ACL which prevents your user from retrieving this attribute

See : [slapo-memberof](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-memberof&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release) for more informations

Comment: My problem were the missing credentials in the ldapsearch command. The overlay works fine.